# Can I use labels as index in C global data table?

Tags: c

I have a large global array in which I keep changing some of the values which when compiled for different purposes requires the table to be altered. Basically the table as a core structure and based on different purposes additional values may get added/removed from it.
The values are somewhat like:

```
int global_array[] = 
{
 ...
 6, 6, 78, 9,
 12,
 13,5
 19,
 47, 768, 98, 89
 ...
};
```

I need to access some of core structure values (lets say "12" here) inside these table. So while compiling for different purposes, index of concerned value ("12") changes. For same reason I cannot keep this table as structure. Keep in mind this is a huge table and for some reason we don't write values in uniform fashion (read linear).

So for every new purpose I have to manually count index of value "12" which is tedious. I want a future proof process.

I was wondering if I could use something like:

```
int global_array[] = 
{
 ...
 6, 6, 78, 9,
 INDEX: 12,
 13,5
 19,
 47, 768, 98, 89
 ...
};
```

And access/modify values at run-time as below:

```
*(uint8 *)INDEX = 20;
```

Comment: where you want to place `*(uint8 *)INDEX = 20;` and what you expect it to do?

Comment: Thats just an example of how I intend to access the concerned value in runtime.
Here I basically expected the value "12" in the table to be changed to "20".

Comment: Keep global array as a bunch of arrays and use linker script (supported only by _GNU ld_ as far as i know) to ensure that they their order is correct. Very dirty, but efficient. You may use `memcpy()` to build `global_array` in run-time, but it is slower.

Answer (score 2):

You can keep additional pointer variables around that point to specific entries. Whenever needed, you can adjust the array entry the pointer points to.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int global[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
int *idx = &global[0];

int main() {
    *idx = 20;
    printf("%d\n", *idx);
    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, you could use a preprocessor macro (if the location that is referred to is known at compile time and will not change):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int global[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
#define INDEX (global[0])

int main() {
    INDEX = 20;
    printf("%d\n", INDEX);
    return 0;
}
```

Given you only need to do this once at program start, maybe you just need a function that does the counting for you.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int global[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};

int find_index(int value, int *array, size_t size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        if (array[i] == value)
            return i;
    return -1;
}

int main() {
    int value = 4;
    int index = find_index(value, global, sizeof(global)/sizeof(*global));
    printf("index of %d: %d\n", value, index);
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the output:

```
$ gcc tt.c -std=c99 && ./a.out
index of 4: 3
```

If the positions of lots of entries needs to be tracked throughout the entire runtime of the application you should consider using a key-value storage (e.g., a binary search tree) to keep track of the values' indices. You should then use special methods that encapsulate the update and retrieval operations that will also adjust the indices stored in that "index" data structure.

Comment: Location of INDEX varies as entries are added/removed from table and I don't want to count INDEX every time I alter table.

Comment: @HimanshuRawat Then you could use the first approach (pointer variable) and adjust the pointer according to the changes.

Comment: @HimanshuRawat When you change the position where `12` is stored you'd also need to update the pointer variable to point to the new position. I don't see how this is tedious. Just use a setter-method that encapsulates the operations.

Comment: @HimanshuRawat Are you looking for a data structure that you can use to keep track of the indices of all values in the array? (I'm afraid you have to resort to something as sophisticated as this. There is no simple syntactical feature that will do this for you.)

Comment: This is a huge table and values are bound to get repeated. Searching for a particular value or sequence may not be feasible for performance and accuracy reasons.
Only way I recognize the concerned values is the comments around it.

Comment: I think this completely fails to address the requirement. It also assumes values don't appear multiple times, which is obviously false according to the code provided.

Comment: @HimanshuRawat You mean the comments in the array initialization? Then you either need to redesign your array initialization or use external tools like Jens suggested.

Comment: @Jens As I understood, the index of the variable is subject to change during runtime as well. Therefore I don't acknowledge _complete failure_ given the requirements.

Comment: @moooeeeep I'd say you misinterpret "compiling for different purposes" (which is mentioned twice). That's strong evidence for a compile-time question, no? There's also no way to *initialize* a global array during run-time more than once. You can only modify elements and only if their index does not change.

Comment: Jens is correct. Index does not change dynamically only during compile time. 

This is something very easy to do in assembly. I was looking for simpler solution on similar lines to avoid manual counting.

Answer (score 0):

From ISO/IEC9899:

> 6.8.6.1 The goto statement
>
> Constraints
>
> 1 The identifier in a goto statement shall name a label **located somewhere in the enclosing function**.
>
> A goto statement shall not jump from outside the scope of an identifier having
> a variably modified type to inside the scope of that identifier.

As a global aray is not located in an enclosed function, this is not allowed!

Comment: Wouldn't even work for local variables. There are only labelled *statements*, never labelled *declarations*.

Answer (score 0):

C does not provide any syntax to do what you want.

One way to solve this so you don't have to count something with each change, is to have a tool of yours do the counting. After all, machines are good at counting things. For example, you could mark the interesting postitions in the initializer with a special comment, i.e.

```
int global_array[] = 
{
 6, 6, 78, 9,
 12,  /* INDEX12 */
 13,5,
 19,
 47, 768, 98, 89
 ...
};
```

The index for the array element is then found by counting the commas from the start of the declaration, minus one. Turn the result into a compile-time macro with `-DINDEX12=42`, et voilà! All you need is an idea of where the declaration starts (putting it in a separate header file is the easy route), and run for example

```
$ awk '/global_array/,/INDEX12/ { commas += gsub(/,/, ",") }
    END {print "-DINDEX12=" commas - 1}' file.h
-DINDEX12=4
```

This is easily extended to deal with any number of `INDEXNNN` macros. Beware of the potential off-by-one for the last array initializer (which doesn't have a comma in your snippet, but C *does* allow it...)
Placing this preprocessing in a snugly `Makefile` left as an exercise.